k-independent hash functions vs. orthogonal arrays
In some randomised algorithms, such as Alon-Matias-Szegedy (AMS) algorithm, two different strategies are used for the generation of a family of random numbers with some special correlation properties:
$$
E[\varepsilon_a]=0,\\
E[\varepsilon_a\varepsilon_b]=\delta_{ab},\\
E[\varepsilon_a\varepsilon_b\varepsilon_c\varepsilon_d]=0 \text{ when $a, b, c, d$ different},\\
E[\varepsilon_a^3\varepsilon_b]=0 \text{ when $a\neq b$},\\
E[\varepsilon_a^2\varepsilon_b\varepsilon_c]=0 \text{ when  $a, b, c$ are different},\\
E[\varepsilon_a^4]=1,\\
E[\varepsilon_a^2\varepsilon_b^2]=1,
$$
where $E$ denotes the expected value, and $\varepsilon_i=\pm1$, with $i=a, b, c, d$.
The first and more common approach is to use polynomial hash functions over a finite field to ensure the $k$-wise independence (second moment AMS algorithm requires 4-independent hash functions). However, in the original Alon-Matias-Szegedy paper, orthogonal arrays are used. This is the second approach.
The second way seems to be quite cumbersome, as one would need to deal with large error correcting codes (such as Bose-Chaudhuri-Hocquenghem codes) that give rise to orthogonal arrays with desired properties.
Therefore, my question is whether the 2 methods are completely equivalent.
I guess no, as $4$-wise independent hash functions only approximately produce orthogonal arrays of strength 4. Otherwise one would use them for the generation of orthogonal arrays. But maybe someone can give more precise explanation?
